# xlwt Cyrillic error

Tags: python, unicode, xlwt

I have a task - write out DB info to xls file.
Execute request to the DB (MySQL), have a list of sql-alchemy instances, get info, something like this:

```
supervisor = full_theme.get_supervisor_name()
performer = full_theme.get_performer_name()
theme = full_theme.theme
print type(theme) # for check, return <type 'unicode'>
```

and in xls book I have no Cyrillic symbols at all. Xls book created with parameter "utf-8".

Comment: It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Comment: question can be closed, seems to have some problems in LibreOffice...